# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the paramter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, null, initialization, provider

I'm new to programming and dont know anything. But right now, im trying to use Provider library at **flutter** and following some guy at youtube. But i got stuck at this situation. At first, **flutter** tell me to add *late* code, but it keep making my app error (LateInitializationError: Frield '_data@*****' has not been initialized.) So im trying to figure out this problem and i think it's about null / unnull something? (please explain this too :3) Anyway here's my code:

example_provider.dart

```
//Before 
//What's the difference between foundation and cupertino?
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
// What is ChangeNotifier?
class ExampleProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
// Why do we need "late"? 
  late String _data;
// What is void ? 
 void setDataString(String data) {
    this._data = data;
// What is notifyListeners(); ?
notifyListeners();
  }
// Why do we need return this._data ?
  String getDataString () {
    return this._data;
  }
}
```

As you can see, this is my **before** code. i add **late** at String_data; because flutter told me so. But @Christoper Moore said in this forum
[LateInitializationError: Field 'data' has not been initialized, got error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401385/lateinitializationerror-field-data-has-not-been-initialized-got-error)

that we must remove the **late** and add Question Mark(?) at our variable. Then i followed the advice/answer and change my code. Here's my **after** code :

example_provider.dart

```
//After  
//What's the difference between foundation and cu
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
// What is ChangeNotifier?
class ExampleProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
// Why do we need "late"? 
   String? _data;
// What is void ? 
 void setDataString(String data) {
    this._data = data;
// What is notifyListeners(); ?
notifyListeners();
  }
// Why do we need return this._data ?
  String? getDataString () {
    return this._data;
  }
}
```

And then this is my homepage (which where the error occured) code :
home.dart

```
import 'package:chapter_5/application/example_provider.dart';
import 'package:chapter_5/presentation/second_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ExampleProvider>(
      builder: (context, exampleProvider, _) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Latihan 5"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(exampleProvider.getDataString()),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("Go To Dashboard"),
                onPressed: () {
                  exampleProvider.setDataString("0");
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          SecondPage(judul: "Ayam", tulisan: "Kodok"),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                style:
                    ButtonStyle(overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                  (states) {
                    return states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)
                        ? Colors.amber
                        : null;
                  },
                )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please answer my question inside my codes too so i can understand more about flutter.
Thank you for answering/trying

Comment: I strongly recommend reading https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety and https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq.

Comment: Your question is a bit all over the place. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i think you better start learning the basics of programming and flutter then use provider

Comment: @Ardeshirojan do you have any good trainer out there? (free one)

Comment: @JimmY youtube is full of free tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway i figured it out guys.
If you following my question, there's a *before* code on **example_provider.dart**
Using this code, and i'll have a new error saying **Lateinilization....** and then,
i deleted the **late String _data;** code into **String _data = "";** since the null safety needed a value.

```
//Before 

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
class ExampleProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  String _data = "";
 void setDataString(String data) {
    this._data = data;    notifyListeners();
  }
  String getDataString () {
    return this._data;
  }
}
```

Therefore my code is running without an error.
Thank you me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code in _HomePageState Widget build:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ExampleProvider>(
      builder: (context, exampleProvider, _) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Latihan 5"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(exampleProvider.getDataString()!),
                /* This is the line where the error occurs.
                   It happens because getDataString is nullable
                   You must add a bang operator to make it non-nullable*/
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("Go To Dashboard"),
                onPressed: () {
                  exampleProvider.setDataString("0");
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          SecondPage(judul: "Ayam", tulisan: "Kodok"),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                style:
                    ButtonStyle(overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                  (states) {
                    return states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)
                        ? Colors.amber
                        : null;
                  },
                )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Refer to the [bang operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#how-do-i-signal-that-the-return-value-from-a-map-is-non-nullable) for more.

Comment: Using my after code at example_provider.dart,
And following your instruction, the reuslt is still an error
'Null check operator used on a nul value'

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`String? value` means that `value` is a variable that can be `null` or a `String`

e.g.:

```dart
// This is ok
value = "Hello World";

// This is also ok;
value = null;
```

If you don't assign anything to `value`, it is null by default.

This error:

> The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the paramter type 'String'

it means that you are trying to assign a `String?` (`String` or `null`) to a `String` (cannot be null).

> Why do we need "late"?

Because if you say `String data`, data is `null`, and `String` cannot be null. If you put `late` it is ignoring this constraints, and it will *assume* that somewhere else in the code (later) you will give it a value.

Comment: So according to your answer, i must remove this question mark at "String?" code right? And add late before String _data; ?

It still error saying : LateInitializationError: Field '_data@****' has not been initialized.

Comment: No I didn't say remove the `?`. I'm saying ***IF*** you use `late`, you need to be sure to assign something to it before using it. Otherwise it is `null` and that's an error. Try assigning it a value in the very beginning of the `build()` method, for example

Comment: I don't think I can explain better than this. You're going to have a very difficult time if you don't try to understand the basics.  ****read the documentation*** https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: Thank you for your time tho. Appreciate it~