# LateInitializationError: Field 'searchResults' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I tried to used google map autocomplete, but I got the this error `LateInitializationError: Field 'searchResults' has not been initialized.`

How can solve it problem?

I still tried to used this way, but still falue.

```
void initState() {
searchResults;
}
```

This is my code

```
late List<PlaceSearch> searchResults;
  final placeService = PlaceSerive();

  searchPlaces(String searchTerm) async {
    searchResults = await placeService.getAutoComplete(searchTerm);
  }
...
...
void initState() {
searchResults;
}
...
...
...

 child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: searchResults.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text(searchResults[index].description,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LateInitializationError: Field 'data' has not been initialized, got error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67401385/lateinitializationerror-field-data-has-not-been-initialized-got-error)

Comment: @MendelG it's not can solve, I had tried it before.

Comment: Did you mean to call searchPlaces() inside initState()? searchResults; doesn't do anything. You can also initialize it with an empty list [] and remove the late keyword.

Answer (score 0):

While `searchResults` will get data from future it is better to use FutureBuilder for statelesswidget or nullabe data.

On state class

```dart
  List<PlaceSearch>? searchResults;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchPlaces("yourSearchTerm")
  }

 searchPlaces(String searchTerm) async {
    searchResults = await placeService.getAutoComplete(searchTerm);
    setState((){});
  }
```

Now you can check whether list is null or not.

```dart
child: searchResults==null? Text("loading") :ListView.builder(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `searchPlaces` function in the init function so it can't initialize the searchResults variable. To solve it do this:

```
@override
initState(){
  super.initState();
  searchPlaces();  
}
```

and remember to set state in searchPlaces function.